# Tkinter TclError : Item not found

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

This is going to be something very basic that Im stuck on. `"Column11"` in my treeview has a selection box linked to it. Once a row is highlighted and the value from the selection box is selected the value will be input to the selected row `"Column11"`. Works perfectly. Now Im trying to write a function `Clear_Status` that will clear the value from the previous input into `"Column11"`. I keep getting back `TcLError: Item Column11 not found.` Does this mean I need to callback the value from `"Column11"` before clearing?? Or more than likely an issue with my `clear_status` function... Ive cut the code down to include what I assumed to be necessary.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as tkrttk
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageTk
import csv


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("2000x1000")
filepath = (r"")
root.title(filepath)
style = tkrttk.Style()
style.configure("Treeview.Heading", foreground='Red', font=('Helvetica', 10))

treetime['columns'] = ("Column11")

treetime.place(x=0, y=60)
treetime.column("#0", width=0)

treetime.column("Column11", width=200, minwidth=100)



Status = StringVar()
Status.set(0)

# Function to apply status name to Column11 "Current Satus"


def set_status(value):
    row = treetime.focus()
    treetime.set(row, 'Column11', value)


def set_status(value):
    row = treetime.focus()
    if row:
        treetime.set(row, 'Column11', value)


def clear_status():
    row = treetime.focus()
    treetime.selection_remove(row, 'Column11')



# Drop Down box
drop = tkrttk.OptionMenu(root, Status, "Select Status", *StatusList, command=set_status)
drop.place(x=950, y=0, height=50, width=150)
#Clear Status buton
ClearStatus_Button = Button(root, text="Clear Status", command = clear_status, width="30", height="3")
ClearStatus_Button.place(x=1150, y=0, height=50, width=150)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If I'm understanding the treeview documentation correctly, `.selection_remove()` has no need for a column identifier - so that `'Column11'` is being treated as a (nonexistent) second *row* to remove from the selection.

Comment: I had noticed that, but if I use `treetime.selection_remove(row')` how does it know which column to remove the value from

Comment: I managed to re-write the `clear_status` function, it now deletes the entire row which isnt what I want but close.. `def clear_status():
    rows = treetime.selection()
    for row in rows:
        treetime.delete(row)`

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do in `clear_status()`.  If you just want to clear the content, call `treetime.set(row, 'Column11', '')`.

Comment: A simple solution to something I was over complicating. Thank you very much